# Data retrieve on Data Change in firebase getting Error

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am making an android app based on firebase. My logcat showing error on data change. Here is the code:

```
myRef.child("first").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    model model = childSnapshot.getValue(model.class);
                    if (dataSnapshot.getValue() == null) {
                       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Sorry",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {

                        String name = model.getFb01name();
                        

                        tvName.setText(name);
                        

                    }

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }


        });
```

Can anybody improve it?

Here is my logcat error message: It is showing error on this line.

```
 model model = childSnapshot.getValue(model.class);
```

"at my_project_name.SheetActivity$3.onDataChange(SheetActivity.java:156)"

```
2020-11-23 17:41:35.403 5585-5585/my_project_name E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: my_project_name, PID: 5585
    com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.Long to type my_project_name.Model.model
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertBean(CustomClassMapper.java:436)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass(CustomClassMapper.java:232)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertToCustomClass(CustomClassMapper.java:80)
        at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(DataSnapshot.java:203)
        at my_project_name.SheetActivity$3.onDataChange(SheetActivity.java:156)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(ValueEventRegistration.java:75)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(DataEvent.java:63)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(EventRaiser.java:55)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

I have tried a lot. Sometimes it worked but stopped again. I cannot point out where is the mistake.

my model class goes as follow:

```
public class model {
    private String fb01name;
   


    public model() {
    }

    public model(String fb01name) {
        this.fb01name = fb01name;
        
    }

    public String getFb01name() {
        return fb01name;
    }

    public void setFb01name(String fb01name) {
        this.fb01name = fb01name;
    }

}
```

My firebase structure is like this:

[image: this is my data structure]

This the latest logcat message after applying the suggestion:

```
2020-11-24 00:40:06.783 12399-12399/my_project_nameE/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: my_project_name, PID: 12399
    com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert value of type java.lang.Long to String
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertString(CustomClassMapper.java:426)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass(CustomClassMapper.java:217)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToType(CustomClassMapper.java:179)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$100(CustomClassMapper.java:48)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.deserialize(CustomClassMapper.java:593)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.deserialize(CustomClassMapper.java:563)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertBean(CustomClassMapper.java:433)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass(CustomClassMapper.java:232)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertToCustomClass(CustomClassMapper.java:80)
        at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(DataSnapshot.java:203)
        at my_project_name.SheetActivity$3.onDataChange(SheetActivity.java:155)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(ValueEventRegistration.java:75)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(DataEvent.java:63)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(EventRaiser.java:55)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Comment: can you share you database structure please? Also your Model class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here try this, if your model class has only one parameter this should be fine. If you need all the parameters that are in your database, you will need to extract all from database and then add it to your model.

```
myRef.child("first").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
      String name = (String) dataSnapshot.child("fb01name").getValue().toString;
        if(name == null){
        
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Sorry",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        
        }
    
        model model = new model(name);
        tvName.setText(name);
    
    
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
    
    }

});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @ Taha Malik. It worked correctly .I just added 'Value' after 'get' in the end of the fourth line. Should I repeat the same trick for other parameters that are in my database.

Answer (score 1):

Since you read from `first`, the `DataSnapshot` that you get in `onDataChange` contains the data at that location. You then loop over the children in the snapshot, so your `childSnapshot` variable then points to the individual properties under `first` (so `fb00max`, `fb01mark1`, etc). And when you then try to read a `model` object from that single value, it fails as the value `10` can't be interpreted as a `model`.

You'll either have to read from one level higher in the tree, or remove the loop from your `onDataChange`.

#### read from one level higher in the tree

```
myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    ...
```

#### remove the loop from your `onDataChange`

```
myRef.child("first").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        model model = dataSnapshot.getValue(model.class);
        if (dataSnapshot.getValue() == null) {
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Sorry",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            String name = model.getFb01name();
            
            tvName.setText(name);                    
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
        throw error.toException(); // Never ignore errors
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Frank van Puffelen for taking pains to solve the problem. I applied both of your suggestions one by one but none of them worked. The application closes abruptly after reaching the targeted point.

Comment: "none of them worked" is not easy to follow up on. I'm quite sure the behavior changes when you apply either of these, so please debug and tell where and how the application fails after applying one of the other.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Frank van Puffelen for a prompt reply. I have posted the logcat error message which I received after removing the loop.